# Adding a negative lookahead to a URL matching Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

So I'm tryin to replace all text URLs in multiple elements on my page with that URL in anchor tags:

`http://google.com` => `<a target="_blank" href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>`

```
var titles = document.querySelectorAll(".title");
var l = titles.length, i, title;
    for(i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    console.log('foo')
    title = titles[i];
    title.innerHTML = title.innerHTML.replace(/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig,"<a target='_blank' href='$1'>$1</a>")
}
```

The problem is I have to run the regex again after some AJAX comes back and it's re-applying the anchor tags to the urls in the `href=""` attribute of the anchor tags! So I need to add a negative lookahead to this regex that prevents it from matching any urls with a trailing `"` or `'`.

Do match `http://google.com` but don't match `"http://google.com"`

`/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general lookahead technique to assert that something is not inside double quotes is to check that there is an even number of them until the end of the string:

```
yourPatternHere(?=[\s\S]*(?:"[\s\S]*"[\s\S])*$)
```

But you are operating on HTML. This may cause all sorts of problems (unmatched quotes in text nodes, comments, single quote delimited attribute values and so on). [Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Instead use JavaScript's built-in DOM manipulating capabilities as far as possible. Don't just find the `.title` elements, but traverse their text nodes instead and apply the replacement only to those.

Comment: I tried switching to the function provided here: http://jsfiddle.net/mAJkL/ which transverses DOM nodes, is this what I should be using?

Comment: @JacksonGariety that looks better, yes